# Lost Wordpress site on Raspberry Pi4

Tags: router, apache-http-server, mysql, raspberry-pi, wordpress

Recently my router died and we have installed a spanking new fibre system with a new Google Wi-Fi mesh. Unfortunately the website on my RP no longer loads. I have assigned a new static IP to the Pi on my router but that didn't work.
The system is an Apache2, PHP, MySQL setup. I loaded up a fresh SD card with a new WordPress database which worked fine on that IP.

Presumably in my tinkering I've messed up some settings but as a bit of an amateur, it's beyond me what I've done.

It returns this message-
This site can’t be reached [www.davidhallows.com](http://www.davidhallows.com) refused to connect.

Any help would be awesome, there's a whole load of blog posts I could do with not losing.

Answer (score -1):

It is really hard to give a good reply with so few details but my first guess would be that you have a firewall blocking ports 80 and 443 making your website unreachable.

Try to look in your router config to open those ports and forward them to your RPI's IP address:

1. Open the Google Home app Google Home app.
2. Tap Wi-Fi  and then Settings  and then Advanced Networking.
3. Tap Port management and then Add .
4. Select the tab for the type of IP address you're forwarding.
5. Select a device.
6. Add your internal and external ports.

   - For IPv4: Choose an internal port used by the device on the local network and an external port on the WAN. You can enter a single port number (#) or a port range (####-####).
     Note: When entering a port range internal and external ranges need to be the same. This is not the case for single port forwarding.
   - For IPv6: Enter the port range.
     Note: Some devices will suggest what ports to use, while others let you choose. If you don’t know which ports to forward, contact the device manufacturer or check the device's manual.
7. Choose either Transmission Control Protocol (TCP), User Datagram Protocol (UDP), or TCP/UDP. These are different protocols used to send data over the internet.
8. Tap Save .

(instructions from: https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/6274503?hl=en)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for swift response jdespraz! I opened the ports and something worked, temporarily. It told me the site was unsafe, so I checked the advanced settings which threw up the opening page with the redline through the https part. Unfortunately it now gives me the error -

This page isn’t workingwww.davidhallows.com didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Any ideas, or other specific information I'd need to post?

Thanks again.

Comment: The safe/unsafe warning is probably due to the SSL certificate that is used by your webserver. If it is self-signed, it will not be trusted by your browser. You can generate a valid certificate using a service like letsencrypt: https://letsencrypt.org/ and you won't have that issue anymore. (if you are using http only, which I don't recommend, you won't have this issue).

Comment: The issue with the EMPTY_RESPONSE is most probably due to an error in your wordpress webserver. Just another remark: be careful when trying things out now that your RPI is accessible from the internet, make sure you do not expose sensitive data.

Comment: Thanks again, yes, the lets encrypt licences expire in a few days. 

In regards to the wordpress server, I'm not sure how to access it, previously I'd go in through the admin panel but none of it will load.

Comment: Hard to tell, as I don't know your exact setup but I would say, first make a backup of your old wordpress data and mysql database. Then, try to reinstall Apache2, PHP and, if needed, MySQL and load back your data. You will need to do this through your PI desktop or terminal interface. Hope that works out for you!

Comment: Hi Jdespaz
It came back online and is annoyingly inconsistent, sometimes the homescreen appears, and other pages too, then it al drops off, grrr.